# How can I export data from GridDB to a CSV file using SQL?

Tags: sql, database, csv, griddb, data-export

I have a GridDB database and want to export data from a specific container to a CSV file using SQL. I'm familiar with SQL queries but unsure how to achieve this in GridDB.

Here's what I have so far:

```
SELECT * FROM my_container
```

This query retrieves all the data from the my_container container, but I must export it to a CSV file. What additional steps or commands must I include in my SQL query to accomplish this task? Are there any specific GridDB SQL functions or syntax I should use for exporting data to a CSV file?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the import/export tool. Download it from here: https://github.com/griddb/expimp/tree/main

Please read the [manual](https://github.com/griddb/expimp/blob/main/Specification_en.md) on how to use it.
For example to export my_container, you can use the following command::

> gs_export --container my_container -u admin/admin

There is also a how to video if you prefer that:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S1_SJsonYc0&list=PLZiizI6Euect9q64akYBkiqLMS78UTwjO&index=13